# For loop with random number of conditions

Tags: python, for-loop, random

I have this code for filtering lists in Python:

```
column_to_check_for_include = [
    1,
    2,
]  # random result possible , could as well be [0] or [0,1,2] or whatever
column_to_check_for_exclude = [
    0,
    2,
    3,
]  # random result possible , could as well be [0] or [0,1,2] or whatever


content = [
    ["John", "is", "cool", "sometimes"],
    ["Paul", "is", "bad", "everytime"],
    ["Ringo", "may be", "great", "sometimes"],
    ["Georges", "must be", "small", "yesterday"],
]
include_criteria = ["is", "must be"]
exclude_criteria = ["bad", "sometimes"]

for row in content:
    if all(
        exclude not in row[0]
        and exclude not in row[2]
        and exclude not in row[3]
        for exclude in exclude_criteria
    ):
        if any(
            include in row[1] or include in row[2]
            for include in include_criteria
        ):
            print(row)
            # output ['Georges', 'must be', 'small', 'yesterday']
```

I would like to do the same by replacing all the `row[number]` by iterating through the lists `column_to_check_for_include` and `column_to_check_for_exclude`, knowing that those 2 lists content will change each time the user update them.

Something like :

```
for row in content:
    if all(
        exclude not in row[column_to_check_for_exclude[0]]
        and exclude not in row[column_to_check_for_exclude[1]]
        and exclude not in row[column_to_check_for_exclude[2]]
        for exclude in exclude_criteria
    ):
        if any(
            include in row[column_to_check_for_include[0]]
            or include in row[column_to_check_for_include[1]]
            for include in include_criteria
        ):
            print(row)
```

Maybe I need to re-think the whole approach but I don't know how to deal with the fact that the number of conditions will change in the `if` statements (depending on the number of items in the lists).

Thanks

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and not not leave out important parts in your question. Like: 1) What do you want to achieve (not in pseudo-code, but in understandable language)  2) What programming language are you using?   3) What is the expected output?

Comment: Can't be more clear as I provided a full example

Comment: Please read (also) the second, and third, part of my comment.

Comment: Sorry I missed that, I would like strict python and the output depends on the 2 lists content and number of item as they are changing all the time.

Comment: I try to iterate thgrough column_to_check_for_include and column_to_check_for_exclude to replace the row[numbers] so if those 2 list content change, the loop will adapt itself to the changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

afaiu, your problem is simply one of nested loops in list-comprehensions:

```py
for row in content:
    if all(
        exclude not in row[r]
        for exclude in exclude_criteria
        for r in column_to_check_for_exclude
    ):
        if any(
            include in row[r]
            for include in include_criteria
            for r in column_to_check_for_include
        ):
            print(row)
```

or even (as a "one-liner"):

```py
matches = [
    row
    for row in content
    if all(
        exclude not in row[r]
        for exclude in exclude_criteria
        for r in column_to_check_for_exclude
    )
    and any(
        include in row[r]
        for include in include_criteria
        for r in column_to_check_for_include
    )
]
print(matches)
```

Comment: Your second proposition did the trick ! Thanks a lot